# Make an optional Where Clause in mysql

Tags: html, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Here's a [fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb454/4).

Can anyone tell me how to make an optional Where Clause in this statement?

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.name,.u.shipping_countries,
       u.contact,s.toy_id,s.price
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN Sales_info s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
LEFT JOIN Toy t ON s.toy_id = t.toy_id
WHERE u.name = 'John' 
( ???AND s.toy_id = '222' ???)
```

My expected output should be:

```
USER_ID NAME    SHIPPING_COUNTRIES  CONTACT TOY_ID  PRICE
3        John   Europe              gmail   222     (null)
```

Would `CASE` possibly work? I have tried `Case When s.toy_id = '222' ELSE 1=1 END`, but obviously it is not correct.

Background:

I have a html form that allows sellers to submit their prices on every product page if they are also selling the product they are browsing.

The form is pulled in dynamically via Ajax. I want to make a query first to try to retrieve some basic information, if they have any, from the seller table to fill in as many input forms as possible. For example, if they have already filled in the basic info like shipping countries and contact on other pages, those details will be the default values in the input forms when they are pulled in on the page for Toy B.

```
  <form>
    <input type='hidden' value='222' name='toy_id'/>
    <input type='text' value='Tom' name='user_name'/>
    <input type='text' value='' name='product_page_url'/>
    <input type='text' value='' name='price'/>
    <input type='text' value='Europe,Asia' name='shipping_countries'/>
    <input type='text' value='my@gmail.com' name='contact'/>
    <input type='submit'>
   </form>
```

And if they have submitted their prices for Toy B already, the form will show all of the values they have entered previously so that they can modify/update them.

Comment: `where foo='bar' or foo is null`?

Comment: @MarcB No.  Doesn't work.  If a user has other toys in sales_info then all the rows for that user get joined - no rows with s.toy_id null and no rows with both user John and toy_id 222 since all the rows for user john have other toy ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always want to match a single toy id but only if that users sells that toy then you can join a sub-select of just that toy:

```
SELECT u.user_id,u.name,.u.shipping_countries,
       u.contact,s.toy_id,s.price
FROM User u 
LEFT JOIN (select * from Sales_info where toy_id = 222) s ON u.user_id = s.user_id
LEFT JOIN Toy t ON s.toy_id = t.toy_id
WHERE u.name = 'John'
```

That way, if the user for that toy doesn't match the chosen user the left join takes care of still giving you info from the user table.

Note sure about the effectiveness of this on a large db, since we can't use indexes in the join.  But if we always selecting one row from dales_info then it shouldn't be too bad I hope.  It works at least.